# Google Maps not loading all tiles (From any of my computers in Dubai)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am developing a Google Maps based site and have a problem that occurs in my site. Randomly, I get a message on tiles saying "Sorry, we have no imagery here". This issue occurs on all my computers/browsers and only in satellite view.

The problem is not consistent and sometimes I get the same problem when browsing the google maps api samples or http://wikimapia.org which rules out the possibility of a javascript/css error.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am no longer encountering this problem now with the same internet connection.  It seems it was a technical issue from Google Maps that is solved now.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are on a slower network, there is nothing you can do  to eliminate this as far as writing your own javascript  is concerned.

Comment: Not quite... The google api examples are working fine now whereas my site isn't.

Comment: Satellite imagery is banned by some governments in sensitive areas.  Like parts of Israel since they have enemies.  Isn't that The Palm Islands in Dubai?  They might consider that a miltary target too.

Comment: This is just an example. Any place on the globe has the same problem. Sometimes a tile is not displayed but when you zoom down the details of that tile are loaded properly. Zoom back up and you see the same damn tile saying "no imagery here"

Comment: can you post your code in a fiddle, so that we say if this repeats

Comment: I have a dedicated server in the USA and it is working fine from there.  I am only having problems here in Dubai.